# Why is Windows offering multiple keyboard layouts?

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout

From time to time, Windows start offering me multiple Czech layouts:

[image]

I only ever use **Czech QWERTY** and don't have anything else enabled in language preferences:

[image]

How do I remove the additional keyboard layouts from the language menu, and more importantly, from Alt+Shift cycling?

Comment: Check `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Language` and `Options`. Please [edit] the question and add output from `Get-WinUserLanguageList` (PowerShell).