# Where is the additional keyboard layout coming from?

Tags: keyboard-layout, windows-11

I have only two languages installed in my system: *English (Australia* and *Polish*.

[image]

Each of these two languages has only one keyboard layout (and both has the same): *Polish (Programmers)*. Yet, when I press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, I see third language and third copy of above mentioned keyboard layout:

[image]

Following [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1262087/why-is-windows-offering-multiple-keyboard-layouts#comment1892751_1262087) I have listed all the languages installed in my system using `Get-WinUserLanguageList` command executed in PowerShell and the list again shows only two languages:

[image]

Where is the additional language and keyboard layout coming from and how to get rid of it?

Comment: [This is a long standing bug with Windows 10+](https://superuser.com/questions/1092246/how-to-prevent-windows-10-from-automatically-adding-keyboard-layouts-i-e-us-ke?noredirect=1&lq=1) [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1680608/how-to-get-rid-of-us-language-in-windows-11?noredirect=1&lq=1) is an updated answer.

Comment: It is a very long standing bug, but I did a fresh install of Windows 10 in 2022 to make a virtual machine and the bug is not there. I suggest just living with it unless you wish to risk a fresh install. I had the same bug in older builds of WIN10.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me into the correct direction (adding and removing _English (United Kingdom)_ did solve the problem). So we have a pure duplicate here. I have just VTC with correct reason.